# Error Code: 1411. How do I change a field’s data type from text to date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to change the Date field (from table bus_delay) format using `UPDATE`, `SET` and `str_to_date()` so I may later change the field data type from text to date.

Date field as below:

| Date |
| --- |
| 1-Jan-22 |
| 2-Jan-22 |
| 3-Jan-22 |

When I run the following:

```
UPDATE bus_delay
SET Date = str_to_date(Date, "%d-%m-%y");
```

I receive the action response:
Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '1-Jan-22' for function str_to_date

I believe I am using `str_to_date()` correctly, please correct me if I am wrong.

Note: When I execute:

```
DESCRIBE ttc_sql_project.bus_delay;
```

The field 'Date' returns a type of 'text'.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? [Edit] your question to include the expected result.

Comment: @PM77-1 question has since been answered and resolved. However, I have updated the question for future clarity.

Comment: Interesting question. I didn't realize that when the text-based column is in the format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s" (or "%Y-%m-%d") it can be converted in-place to DATETIME (or DATE), using:
`ALTER TABLE bus_delay MODIFY Date datetime;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format string is wrong.  This:

```
"%d-%m-%y"
```

Is looking for a date in this format:

```
"01-01-22"
```

But the format you have is:

```
"1-Jan-22"
```

[Fix the format string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
"%e-%b-%y"
```